# gsub regex pattern

Tags: regex, shell, gsub

I am using gsub to substitute tabs with commas

```
gsub(/\t/,\",\")

a\tb will be a,b
```

In some instances I have two tabs follwed by each other
For example

```
a/t/tb
```

In that case gsub converts it to `a,,b`
I want that in cases like that, the string should be converted to a,-,b (a minus sign in between).

I tried writing two sepearate gsubs

```
gsub(/\t/,\",\") // for tab

gsub(/,,/,\"/,-,/\") // for consecutive commas
```

The second doesn't seem to work.

Whats wrong with it. Is there a way, I can combine both in one `gsub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're asking about awk?
I don't think it can be done with a single gsub, in fact I needed three:

```
$ abc=$(echo 'a.b..c...d....e.....f' | tr . '\t')

$ echo "$abc" | awk '{gsub(/\t/, ","); gsub(/,,/, ",-,"); gsub(/,,/, ",-,"); print}'
a,b,-,c,-,-,d,-,-,-,e,-,-,-,-,f
```

The problem is that a single gsub on `/,,/` will consume both commas, so it will leave a gap between the next pair of commas, if there are three or more consecutive ones. In a more powerful regexp engine, such as Perl, it can be done in a single pass using a lookahead:

```
$ echo "$abc" | perl -pe 's/\t/,/g; s/,(?=,)/,-/g;'
a,b,-,c,-,-,d,-,-,-,e,-,-,-,-,f
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was using it with awk.